# What will be the gradient of $f(x,y) = xy$, if $y = x^2$, is it $3x^2$ or $(y,x)$?

Tags: calculus

I am confused with the notation. Gradients use the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ symbol which refers to partial derivative where we keep $y$ as constant even if it is a function of $x$ [source](https://openmdao.github.io/PracticalMDO/Notebooks/Differentiation/totals_vs_partials.html). This would give us $\nabla f(x,y) = (y,x)$.

In contrast if we treat gradient as total derivative (which has the symbol $\frac{d}{dx}$), we would first replace $y$ by $x^2$, and then compute the derivative giving us  $\nabla f(x,y) = 3 x^2$. What is the correct approach for computing the gradient of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: The problem is that asking for the gradient is ambiguous. The gradient of $f$ as a two-dimensional scalar function is $(x, y)$, while the gradient of $f(x, y(x))$ w.r.t. $x$ is $3x^2$. You should determine the meaning of the question from the context.